# How to iterate through a set of buttons in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make my first app which has a set of 15 buttons. when you press a button the color changes between two numbers.Then if you press a specificity different "commit" button the buttons won't change colors any more.

My question right now is how would I be able to iterate through the buttons on the screen? I believe I need a assign the buttons a "name", "type", or something like it, and then find all instances where that happens but I cannot find the relevant getter/setter methods. 
Here is my code so far:

```
public void clickHandler(View view) {

    Button btn = (Button) view;
    int id = btn.getId();
    boolean clicked = isChosen(btn);
    if( clicked == true && id != 1) {
        btn.setBackgroundColor(-3355444);
    }
    else{
        btn.setBackgroundColor(-16777216);
    }

}

public boolean isChosen(Button btn){
    ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();
    int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
    if(colorId == -16777216){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

public boolean player = true;

public void changeTurn(View view) {
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    if(player == false) {
        t.setText("Player 2's turn");
        player = true;
    }
    else{
        t.setText("Player 1's turn");
        player = false;
    }
```

Comment: Are all the button views stored in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this piece of code helps

```
final int buttonCount = 15;
        
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTag(String.valueOf(i));
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int buttonID = Integer.valueOf(view.getTag().toString());

                    updateColorForButtonAtPosition(buttonCount);
                }
            });
            mLayout.addView(textView);
        }

        private void updateColorForButtonAtPosition (int buttonCount){
            // add your functionality here
        }
```